# SQL Column to TextBox (from ComboBox)

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, combobox, textbox

I have managed to add data into a ComboBox from a column out of my SQL table, but I need the rows from across to display in the rest of the textboxes. (I hope I have worded this correctly).

Here is my code currently:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=ltLeavers;Integrated Security=True")

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable", con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "DISPLAY_NAME"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub
```

The above works with no issues, all of the items add into the ComboBox but I need the corresponding rows from the other two columns which are EMAIL_ADDRESS and DEPARTMENT to add into TextBoxes from what is selected in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the `SelectedIndex_Changed` event of the ComboBox; Enter the following code.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=ltLeavers;Integrated Security=True")

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "DISPLAY_NAME"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Textbox1.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)("EMAIL_ADDRESS"))
    Textbox2.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)("DEPARTMENT"))
End Sub
```

You Will need to declare the data table dt outside your form's load event so it can be visible to the SelectedIndex_Changed event of the combo box.

Comment: I don't think I have done this correctly. I am receiving System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0'  

`Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        TextBox1.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)("EMAIL_ADDRESS"))
        TextBox3.Text = CStr(dt.Rows(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)("DEPARTMENT"))

    End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `BindingSource` to get it done.

Try this:

1- Declare your variable type of `BindingSource` with events. Also, declare your dataset will be used for data.

```
Dim WithEvents BS As New BindingSource
Dim ds As New DataSet
```

2- In your `Form` `Load` Event, query your data and bind it with both Binding Source and your `ComboBox` control.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=ltLeavers;Integrated Security=True")
   Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable", con)
   da.Fill(ds, "myPopulatedTable")

   ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "id"
   ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables("myPopulatedTable")

   'Here the new code'
   BS.DataSource = ds
   BS.DataMember = "myPopulatedTable"

End Sub
```

3- Add a `Sub Procedure` to display your data into other text boxes controls.

```
Private Sub DISPLAYRECORD(Optional ByVal table As String = "myPopulatedTable")
        TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables(table).Rows(Me.BS.Position)("column1").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(table).Rows(Me.BS.Position)("column2").ToString()
        TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables(table).Rows(Me.BS.Position)("column3").ToString()
End Sub
```

4- In the `PositionChanged` event of your Binding Source, call that sub procedure (above)

```
Private Sub BS_PositionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BS.PositionChanged
        DISPLAYRECORD()
 End Sub
```

5- Finally, to sync your data with `ComboBox` selection, you need to change the position of that Binding Source according to the `ComboBox` index selection

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        BS.Position = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Why the `DataSet` when there is only one `DataTable`?

Comment: Why not bind the text boxes since you have a binding source?