# How to Get Values of specific row wise in TextBox of a specific column

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

```
Dim Query As String
Query = "Select * from Charges where DOctype='" & Labeldoctype.Text & "'"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(Query, con)
con.Open()

Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(Query, con)
dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
dataAdapter.Dispose()
For i As Integer = 0 To (dt.Rows.Count - 1)
    rowindex = i
    LabelV001.Text = (dt.Rows(0)("Head")).ToString
    LabelV002.Text = (dt.Rows(1)("Head")).ToString

Next
con.Close()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Maybe similar ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440570/sql-column-to-textbox-from-combobox/54442158?noredirect=1#comment95708353_54442158